# How to turn on a remote battery-operated Raspberry Pi (accessible by Wifi or SSH)?

Tags: wifi, power, power-supply, battery, power-management

I am running a cluster of Pi3 and Pi4. Each node runs on a battery and is powered by a solar panel, in a remote area like a farm with no grid. Pis are connected to each other by WiFi in a local network.
I have a program running on a controller/manager Pi in this cluster that sometimes turns a Pi off to save energy. But, I have no idea how to turn Pis on?

One possibility is to ask the Pi to turn itself on every X minutes and ask the controller if it is time to be back!

Another possibility is that the Pi benefits from an attached microcontroller that has a battery itself and WiFi. The controller Pi can communicate with this to turn the Pi on!

Another possibility is to signal the Pi to turn on.

However, I have no idea how to achieve any of these or a different solution.

Comment: `ask the Pi to turn itself on every X minutes` - you may as well ask your toaster to turn itself on - best bet is a battery powered microcontroller with wifi (ESP32/ESP8266 comes to mind), and have that turn the pi on (relay? reset? GPIO3?) somehow - there's no method for a pi to turn itself on, as it has as much ability to do so as a toaster as I previously mentioned

Comment: There are a lot of answers to your question. If you define it better we could give you a better solution. Adafruit sells a device "Adafruit TPL5110 Low Power Timer Breakout" that will probably do what you want. You can find many other similar devices. Check into watchdog timer circuits where you may simply have to invert the logic to make one work.

Answer (score 0):

The attached microcontroller concept is the way to go - this may be helpful
https://www.instructables.com/Turn-Raspberry-Pi-ON-w-Remote-Control/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).